# Is there a method in the Bitcoin RPC API to view all transaction records of a given address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I used the listtransactions method to get transaction records, but it returned an empty collection.[image]

Is it a configuration file problem or other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core only tracks your own wallet’s addresses. If you want to look up a foreign address, either you have to import it to a watch-only wallet and rescan, or use a different software that has an address index.

The ability to look up any address is usually associated with the functionality of blockchain explorers. You could either use the API of one of many publicly available blockchain explorers, or run your own version of e.g. the [Mempool block explorer project](https://github.com/mempool/mempool) or [Esplora](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora).

Comment: What software has the function that has an address index?